# SyntaxError: missing variable name?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have an ejs code to create a temp vector.

```
 <% var temp=[];
   for (i = 0; i < his.length; i++) { 
        temp[i]=  his[i].temp;
};%>
```

The variable "his" comming from the server then inside a script tag i have this.

```
var tempe = <%= temp; %>
console.log(tempe);
```

I got the `SyntaxError: missing variable name`

what can I do?

Note: Mozilla debugger shows tempe as

```
tempe= 76,74,24,29,69,59,44`
```

Comment: Which line throws that error? On the server or on the browser?

Comment: Tempe line inside the script tag, the error is showed in the browser console, everything seens ok to me i dont know what is happening

Comment: Is it not for `for (var i...)`?

Comment: no, the error is inside script tag in 'Var tempe = <%= temp; %>'

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the array as an array...

`var tempe = <%= temp; %>` is going to the browser as `tempe = 76,74,24,29,69,59,44` as you're seeing in the debugger. What you really want is:

```
tempe = [76,74,24,29,69,59,44];
```

which you can get by doing this:

```
var tempe = <%-JSON.stringify(temp)%>;
```

or less neatly, this:

```
var tempe = [<%= temp; %>];
```